# How to implement single sign on with two sample angular apps having the same login credentials

Tags: angular, single-sign-on

I have two sample applications in angular2 **first** with name **admin-app** 
and **second** with name **user_app** where in,

**First application** I have only admin component,when he logs in navigates to admin page. And it has only admin page where admin needs to perform some of the admin related tasks and by clicking **Go To Application** button , admin must be able to access **home page** of user_app i.e **Second application**

```
&
```

**Second application** I have admin & manager user but no admin component, when manager logs in navigates to home page of the application.

I want to implement SSO (Single Sign On) for the two application such that when the admin logs in the **First application** and navigates to admin page then from admin page clicking on button **Go To Application** , he should be redirected to home page of the **second application** without entering the login credentials again.

Below shown is the directory structure of both applications **admin_app** & **user_app**

[image]

Please access my sample applications here

[admin_app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/admin-app?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

[user_app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/user-app?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

please suggest me a possible way out to implement SSO for the two sample applications.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're not processing your authentication in your Angular applications, but deferring to some authentication process on your backend server?

Comment: ya .... earlier the two applications were combined so i required that authentication to avoid other users than admin to access admin component..

Comment: but now i dont require that guard ,so i just removed that CanActivate  guard from my routing component..

Comment: I checked your code, and your entire authentication process takes place on the client-side (i.e. in your Angular application). So, you might as well remove the authentication completely. It's pointless.

Comment: yes ,,, it's not being used .... I will do that .... but can you please suggest me a way how can I implement SSO for both of my sample applications...?

Comment: How are you planning to implement your backend? NodeJS? JavaEE? Spring Boot? Ruby on Rails? PHP? Go?

Comment: its through springboot

Comment: can it be done totally on angular side.?

Comment: Why are you implementing authentication? To make sure that unauthorized parties are not able to access your application, right? If you implement it on the Angular side, I'll just hit the "View source" button in my browser and get the username and password from the source code, making it utterly pointless.

Comment: later i need to integrate my app with backend .. this is a sample where I have manually added user credentials for implementing authentication.

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://auth0.com/docs/sso/current/single-page-apps